How to use a Variable in an R1C1 Formula
I've read many examples of how this can be done on Stack Overflow. However, my syntax is still not right. The formula works fine as is. However, I'm trying to make the formula more dynamic in the event that a column or row gets added or deleted. I've captured the Index IDs for both the column and row that's needed, each in their own variable.
I'm simply trying to replace the R1C1 notation with the two variables that contain the index IDs. Everything has worked up until I tried this. I think I messed up the syntax somewhere, or worse. I've only applied the variables to the first half of the formula. I figured I would get it working then move on to the rest of the formula. Eventually I'll replace the width and height of the offset with a variable that defines the last row and last column, making the entire formula dynamic (or so I hope).
targetSheet is the sheet I'm applying the formula to.
aCellr is the row Index ID.
aCellc is the column Index ID.
Sub somesub
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCellc As Range
    Dim aCellr As Range
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet

    Set sourceSheet = dataWorkbook.Worksheets("Glass Schedule")
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QC")

    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Find Column Index ID
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    With sourceSheet
        strSearch = "Opening #"
        Set aCellc = .Range("A:M").Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlDown, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With

    If Not aCellc Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox (strSearch & " found in column " & aCellc.Column)
    Else
        MsgBox (strSearch & " not found")
    End If

    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Find Row Index ID
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    With sourceSheet
        strSearch = "Opening #"
        Set aCellr = .Range("A:M").Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlDown, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With
    
    If Not aCellr Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox (strSearch & " found in row " & aCellr.Row)
    Else
        MsgBox (strSearch & " not found")
    End If

    ' Comment: Original formula works fine
    
'        .Range("A7").Formula2R1C1 = "=FILTER(FILTER(OFFSET('[" & tgtSheet & "]Glass Schedule'!R8C3,0,0,3001,16),'[" & tgtSheet & "]Glass Schedule'!R8C4:R3008C4<>""""),{1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1})"

    ' Comment: New formula inserted with the variables does not work.
    
        .Range("A7").Formula2R1C1 = "=FILTER(FILTER(OFFSET('[" & tgtSheet & "]Glass Schedule'!R[" & aCellr & "]c [" & aCellc & "],0,0,3001,16),'[" & tgtSheet & "]Glass Schedule'!R8C4:R3008C4<>""""),{1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1})"
    
    End With
End Sub


Brackets look off in "]c [" & aCellc & "],0,0,3001,16). When in doubt, Debug.Print the working formula and the non-working version and compare.

Found my mistake.
'Added the following variables:

Dim rowStart As Integer
Dim colStart As Integer

'Set Variables:
colStart = aCellc.Find(strSearch).Offset(0, 0).Column
rowStart = aCellc.Find(strSearch).Offset(1, 0).Row

'Changed the following line of code:

    .Range("A7").Formula2R1C1 = "=FILTER(FILTER(OFFSET('[" & tgtSheet & "]Glass Schedule'!R" & rowStart & "C" & colStart - 1 & ",0,0,3001,16),'[" & tgtSheet & "]Glass Schedule'!R" & rowStart & "C" & colStart & ":R3008C4<>""""),{1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1})"

